# Dynamically re-linking library optimized for target CPU

Tags: c++, linux, macos, unix, dynamic-linking

I have a library that I would like to compile for different CPU generations (all x86), say I want one to make use of all the instructions Skylake has to offer, a fallback version for Haswell, one for Sandy Bridge and so on. I know I can achieve this with `-march=xyz`, however, I also want to make it easy to use the library. Ideally the user would only have to link against a stub library which then dynamically loads in the correct library optimized for the targets CPU. I know I can achieve this by exporting function pointers in the loader library which are then populated correctly, however, that doesn't really lend itself to a C++ applications since I can't export class methods for example.

Is there any way to force the dynamic linker to re-do the relocation? Ideally the loader library would provide either the most fallback version of the code that runs on all CPUs supported by the library, but can then load a more specialized version, or it really is just a stub library that gets replaced at runtime. Either way, ideally I would like to make it so that the user only ever has to link against one dynamic library and the rest happens automatically at runtime.

Ideally I'd like an answer that works both for Linux and OS X, but I also take one that's only applicable for one of these.

Comment: I guess I can use `excve` and then use something like `LD_PRELOAD`

Comment: I don't see how the dynamic linker is going to figure what CPU architecture it is running on. However, you could load a stub library, have its `_init` (or constructor) function figure out the CPU architecture, then use the 'dl' family of functions (`dlopen`, `dlsym`, etc...) to perform linkage (effectively duplicating the work of the dynamic linker). Sounds like a huge amount of effort though. Probably better off installing the right architecture-dependent library in the first place as part of the package deployment logic (e.g. in `rpm`).